# range(x,y) problems, CSV file updating problems

Tags: python, csv, range

When using different values in range loop, I am receiving different output to file. I think should not be like that. This is the initial content of data.csv:

```
a1,b1,c1
a2,b2,c2
a3,b3,c3
a4,b4,c4
a5,b5,c5
a6,b6,c6
a7,b7,c7
a8,b8,c8
a9,b9,c9
a10,b10,c10
```

This is the script (run on initial content):

```
import csv

csv_f = open("data.csv","r+", newline='')
csv_w = csv.writer(csv_f)

for x in range(1,4):
    csv_w.writerow(["e"+str(x)]+["f"+str(x)]+["g"+str(x)])
    csv_f.flush()   
    
csv_f.close()
```

Output:

```
e1,f1,g1
e2,f2,g2
e3,f3,g3
a4,b4,c4
a5,b5,c5
a6,b6,c6
a7,b7,c7
a8,b8,c8
a9,b9,c9
a10,b10,c10
```

Result as expected.

This is the modified script (range values only) (run on initial content):

```
import csv

csv_f = open("data.csv","r+", newline='')
csv_w = csv.writer(csv_f)

for x in range(12,15):
    csv_w.writerow(["e"+str(x)]+["f"+str(x)]+["g"+str(x)])
    csv_f.flush()   
    
csv_f.close()
```

Output:

```
e12,f12,g12
e13,f13,g13
e14,f14,g14

a5,b5,c5
a6,b6,c6
a7,b7,c7
a8,b8,c8
a9,b9,c9
a10,b10,c10
```

Output is not as expected, a row is lost.

If you play with range values it is doing something that you would not expect with output.

It definitely shouldn't do it. What is the reason? I know there are better ways to open CSV files, but I would like to know what is the problem here. Another example below run on initial content as well.

```
import csv

csv_f = open("data.csv","r+", newline='')
csv_w = csv.writer(csv_f)

for x in range(13,17):
    csv_w.writerow(["e"+str(x)]+["f"+str(x)]+["g"+str(x)])
    csv_f.flush()   
    
csv_f.close()
```

Output:

```
e13,f13,g13
e14,f14,g14
e15,f15,g15
e16,f16,g16
,b6,c6
a7,b7,c7
a8,b8,c8
a9,b9,c9
a10,b10,c10
```

Again the output is not as expected.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you think you need to keep flushing the file inside the loop?

Comment: No, I wasn't doing it on the begining, but I was looking for solution..

Comment: It looks like your script is overwriting a certain amount of content in your CSV; and presumably the number of *characters* that you write are the number that are overwritten. Is that not what you would expect?

Answer (score 0):

You read in the csv into a buffer with `open("data.csv","r+", newline='')`.

This buffer is just a stream of chars. You can imagine it as one string: `a1,b1,c1\r\na2,b2,c2\r\na3,b3,c3\r\na4,b4,c4`

Now you start writing lines to the start of your buffer. First e.g. `e12,f12,g12\r\n`

So it writes the `e` to the first position replacing the `a`

`1` replacing `1`

`2` replacing `,`

Now you can see what this leads too. Because with double-digit numbers you have more chars then before the write behavior is not as you expect.

### Alternative solution:

So to achieve the behavior that I think you wanted you could read in the old lines:

```
rows = []

with open('data.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        rows.append(row)
```

Then you could replace the rows that you want:
In your case you wanted to replace the first four rows:

```
for x in range(0,4):
    offset = 12
    rows[x] = ["e"+str(x+offset)]+["f"+str(x+offset)]+["g"+str(x+offset)]
```

Then you can just specify an offset for the actual content-indice you want (12-15 or whatever)

In the end you just write the rows back:

```
with open('data.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for x in range(0, len(rows)):
        writer.writerow(rows[x])
```

This leads to the following output:

```
e12,f12,g12
e13,f13,g13
e14,f14,g14
e15,f15,g15
a5,b5,c5
a6,b6,c6
a7,b7,c7
a8,b8,c8
a9,b9,c9
a10,b10,c10
```